# How to add billing permissions to config.xml file for cordova phonegap project?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm attempting to add android billing permission to my phonegap cordova project using config.xml. It isn't working.

I've tried using edit-config. I've tried adding xmlns:android to the widget.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.widlugames.theotherside" version="1.1.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>TheOtherSide</name>
    <description>
        An interactive novel
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26"/>
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28"/>

    <platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/uses-permission" mode="merge">
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    </edit-config>
    </platform>

</widget>
```

I expect to be able to upload the apk to google play and be able to add in-app purchases, however when I upload the apk it says I need to add android billing permissions before I can add purchases.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your existing with your existing `platform` tag with the one below and try it:

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
        </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Comment: this unfortunately just so happens to crash my app.